# Overlay EditView on top of custom view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have had varying success trying to overlay my custom view with an `EditView`.

The solution needs to incorporate the fact that my custom view does various calculations which are performed when the canvas is drawn. Calculations such as working out the center X and Y cordinates, dimensions of canvas etc.

These calculation will be used to position the `EditText` on the screen.

So far I have figured out that a `RelativeLayout` is the way to go in regard to the overlaying.

The best solution so far (which is not ideal) is to create a custom `RelativeLayout`, see below:

```
public class MyCustomRL extends RelativeLayout {

    public MyCustomRL(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);
    }

    public MyCustomRL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

    public MyCustomRL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView(context);
    }

    protected void initView(Context context){

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        SeekBar_Speedometer v_speedometer = (SeekBar_Speedometer) inflater.inflate(R.layout.rl_custom_speedometer, this, false);

        addView(v_speedometer);

        RelativeLayout rl_comment = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.rl_edittext_comment, this, false);

        EditText edit = (EditText) rl_comment.findViewById(R.id.edittext_comment);
        edit.setText("Text altered at runtime");

        rl_comment.setX(112);
        rl_comment.setY(117);
        //Log.v("WHATEVER","X: "+v_speedometer.centerX); // = 0
        //rl_comment.setX(v_speedometer.centerX);
        //rl_comment.setY(v_speedometer.centerY);

        addView(rl_comment);
    }
}
```

This essentially works, the `EditText` is positioned at those static coordinates. However I want the EditText to be placed at the `v_speedometer.centerX` and `v_speedometer.centerY`coordinates, but they are 0 because the `v_speedometer` view has not been drawn yet!!!

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't found any solution yet, You can write an interface which will act as your
speedometer hasDrawn listener. It means whenever your speedometer will be drawn just it will post notification to the class implementing your EditText and then set their coordinates again in your CustomView or UI .